# python app (daemon) and systemd fedora

Tags: python, service, daemon, watchdog, systemd

I have python app with loop, which generates some files, saves video images and some other stuff. i installed it on Fedora (17) PC and want it to run "forever", ie if it hangs (i can put some keep_alive in file in loop) - it should be restarted. It also should be started on reboot.
As i understand, python-daemon help to do this, and systemd in Fedora.
I have the following config file for systemd (im not sure on some parameters though as documentation is too complicated for my level of linux knowledge):

```
[Unit]
Description=TPR Daemon

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=always
WorkingDirectory=/home/igor/tpr
PIDFile=/var/run/tpr.pid
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/igor/tpr/testd.py

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

and here is my testd.py:

```
import daemon
import time, sys

class MyDaemon(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print 'I am alive!'
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with daemon.DaemonContext(stdout=sys.stdout):
        check = MyDaemon()
        check.run()
```

when i run it with "sudo systemctl start tpr.service", it hangs for a while and then cancels out with this meesage:

> Warning: Unit file of tpr.service changed on disk, 'systemctl --system daemon-reload' recommended.
>   Job for tpr.service failed. See 'systemctl status tpr.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

and here are some logs from /var/log/messages:

```
Aug  9 21:32:27 localhost systemd[1]: Unit tpr.service entered failed state.
Aug  9 21:32:27 localhost systemd[1]: tpr.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Aug  9 21:32:27 localhost systemd[1]: Stopping TPR Daemon...
Aug  9 21:32:27 localhost systemd[1]: Starting TPR Daemon...
Aug  9 21:33:57 localhost systemd[1]: tpr.service operation timed out. Terminating.
Aug  9 21:33:57 localhost python[28702]: I am alive!
Aug  9 21:33:57 localhost python[28702]: I am alive!
Aug  9 21:33:57 localhost python[28702]: I am alive!
Aug  9 21:33:57 localhost python[28702]: I am alive!
...
Aug  9 21:33:57 localhost python[28702]: I am alive!
Aug  9 21:33:57 localhost python[28702]: I am alive!
Aug  9 21:33:57 localhost python[28702]: I am alive!
Aug  9 21:33:57 localhost python[28702]: I am alive!
Aug  9 21:33:57 localhost systemd[1]: tpr.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug  9 21:33:57 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start TPR Daemon.
Aug  9 21:33:57 localhost systemd[1]: Unit tpr.service entered failed state.
Aug  9 21:33:57 localhost systemd[1]: tpr.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Aug  9 21:33:57 localhost systemd[1]: Stopping TPR Daemon...
Aug  9 21:33:57 localhost systemd[1]: Starting TPR Daemon...
```

so it should be running, but what this error about?
And maybe there is some simple convenient way to accomplish my task, and im inventing bicycle?

Update:

It seems the daemon should somehow let systemd know it has started..but how?

```
Aug 10 01:15:36 localhost systemd[1]: Starting TPR Daemon...
Aug 10 01:17:06 localhost systemd[1]: tpr.service operation timed out. Terminating.
Aug 10 01:17:06 localhost systemd[1]: tpr.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 10 01:17:06 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start TPR Daemon.
Aug 10 01:17:06 localhost systemd[1]: Unit tpr.service entered failed state.
Aug 10 01:17:06 localhost systemd[1]: tpr.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 10 01:17:06 localhost systemd[1]: Stopping TPR Daemon...
Aug 10 01:17:06 localhost systemd[1]: Starting TPR Daemon...
Aug 10 01:18:36 localhost systemd[1]: tpr.service operation timed out. Terminating.
Aug 10 01:18:36 localhost systemd[1]: tpr.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 10 01:18:36 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start TPR Daemon.
Aug 10 01:18:36 localhost systemd[1]: Unit tpr.service entered failed state.
Aug 10 01:18:36 localhost systemd[1]: tpr.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 10 01:18:36 localhost systemd[1]: Stopping TPR Daemon...
Aug 10 01:18:36 localhost systemd[1]: Starting TPR Daemon...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error about changing on the disk means just that the file is changed.
After you run `systemctl daemon-reload` the file will be reread and hten you'll be able to start the service.
You can use notifications as said in [this manual pages](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html). The type for the service is `notify`.
Next thing is: you say your service type as `forking`. Does your process really forks? It is recommended to have `PIDfile` option set up if you use forking.
With systemd it is not necessary to fork your process to become daemon.

Comment: reload error fixed, thank you. my process does not fork, i can hardly yet understand whats that mean, type set as recommended As i understand forking is like child or subprocess, but i have just a loop inside my script. so what type to set in my case? if i set type to "notify" it fails with this:

Aug 11 10:34:08 localhost systemd[1]: Starting TPR Daemon...
Aug 11 10:35:38 localhost systemd[1]: tpr.service operation timed out. Terminating.
Aug 11 10:35:38 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start TPR Daemon.
Aug 11 10:35:38 localhost systemd[1]: Unit tpr.service entered failed state.

Comment: Yes. Whith sysv init system a process should fork itself twice to become daemon. With systemd it does not need it. I hardly understand how systemd works in daemonizing processes (I should take a mocre comprehensive look on its sources).

Surely it is timeout because you don't send notification to the `systemd` with `sd_notify`: http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_notify.html

If you don't use notifications you may set `Type=simple`.

Comment: And one more thing: what does that `import daemon` string do?

Comment: Well, it seems nothing.. app works without being "daemon" or whatever.. it just works now, with "simple" type, thank you!